# I upgraded to Vaadin 24.4.0.alpha3 and now it asks me about the license

Tags: vaadin, licensing, vaadin-flow, vaadin24

After upgrade to Vaadin `24.4.0.alpha3` now it asks me about the license:

```
c.v.pro.licensechecker.LicenseChecker    : Opening system browser to validate license. If the browser is not opened, please open [URL] manually
For CI/CD build servers, you need to download a server license key, which can only be used for production builds. You can download a server license key from https://vaadin.com/myaccount/licenses.
If you are working offline in development mode, please visit [URL] for an offline development mode license.
```

In my application I only use free Vaadin components.

Has something changed, and is there no longer a free version of Vaadin available?

Comment: Have you checked the deps, if you have pulled in commercial packages?

Comment: Actually, no. Everything was working fine on 24.4.0.alpha2. However, on 24.4.0.alpha3, it started asking me for the license. How can I check the dependencies?

Comment: I only changed the version from 24.4.0.alpha2 to 24.4.0.alpha3 in Maven, and that's it.

Comment: In my project Maven deps, I may see for example right now `vaadin-cookie-consent-flow-24.4.0.alpha3.jar`, `vaadin-cookie-consent-testbench-24.4.0.alpha3.jar` but I don't need them

Comment: I downgraded to `24.4.0.alpha2` and everything started working properly. Seems like new changes or a bug

Comment: Keep in mind. It's an alpha version and not ready for production